# OAuth2 Refresh Token Flow - Unsupported Grant Type

Tags: oauth2, rest

I am attempting to obtain a token, using the Oauth 2 refresh token flow.

I am using the REST Console in Chrome to perform the following POST operation:

My URI is https://cs11.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

My Content-Type header is "application/json"

I am posting the following body (client id and secret omitted)

```
{
"client_id":"<supersecret>"
,"grant_type":"authorization_code"
,"client_secret":"<supersecret>"
,"redirect_uri": "https://"
}
```

From what I gather from the saleforce oauth2 refresh token flow documentation, this should work.  However, I am getting the following error for a response:

```
{
    "error_description": "grant type not supported",
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

Any thoughts on why the service doesn't like my grant_type parameter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refresh flow uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, not `application/json`, with a body of the form

```
grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>&refresh_token=<REFRESH_TOKEN>
```

Here's a test I just ran, with credentials removed, and formatting added:

```
$ curl -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>&refresh_token=<REFRESH_TOKEN>' https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
{
    "id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00DE0000000HegHMAS/005E0000000HiFiIAK",
    "issued_at":"1409293734822",
    "scope":"id api refresh_token",
    "instance_url":"https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "signature":"ErVu6WnaaVlXrqLYItISuEm9/nHJIj9GgulS6wlMFnA=",
    "access_token":"<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
}
```

Comment: This is also the same for `grant_type=authorization_code`. You need to have the `Content-Type` header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not `application/json`.

Comment: Obviously it wasn't the issue here, but I saw the same error when sending a `GET` request instead of a `POST`.